# Infopath web form - Submit and switch view

Tags: sharepoint, moss, workflow, infopath

I have an infopath form that I use as part of a MOSS workflow.

The form has multiple views, and a `Save` button on each one. What I want to do as part of the `Save` button's rules, is submit the information and switch to the next view.

I added two rules to the button, one to submit data and another to switch view, but when I re-enter the form, it won't have the information saved.

If I replace the switch view action by a `Close Form` action, however, when I reenter the form it will have all the fields saved (as expected).

Has anyone run into a similar issue? Any workaround?

My form doesn't have any VB or C# code, so there's nothing to post related to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've actually run into similar issues with combining multiple actions with a submit (the submit seems to fire non-deterministically).  I'd highly recommend refactoring the "save" and "switch view" actions into different buttons to avoid these issues.

Comment: I'm being push to keep a single button for usability reasons. Did you try using C# for the actions instead?

Comment: Yes, if you're allowed to deploy a form with code-behind, i'd highly recommend it (you can then have the save, and view-switch occur serially)

Answer (score 0):

By default infopath will open to the default view. which appears to be happening in your case

It seems that you need to use the tools>form options menu item.  under the open and save category there is a open rules behaviour.  from there you can specify the conditions that you want to switch the view

I am using infopath 2007 but 2003 is very similar.